# Azure: Unified logging and End to End tracing

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions

In integration system scenario where we have multiple Azure component with app services.

For example: if a request passes through

**App Service -> APIM -> Logic App -> Event Grid** -> *Function App (Failed)*

How do I trace the request back to source (App Service)?

I gone through documents and options. there is correlation id, but it is not maintained in some of product  like Event Grid or service bus. Log Analytics doesn't have id for logs.

In my findings, I can use AppInsights for App Service and Function Apps. Log Analytics for other components but there is no end to end tracing.

What are the best practices to maintain Azure logs from multiple systems?

Example of [Azure integration service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/enterprise-integration/queues-events): 
[image: Enterprise integration on Azure using message queues and events]

Comment: Generally the way I manage logging in such cases is that I have a custom property called CorrelationID in all my payloads. So in cases of Azure Event Grid or Service Bus, the correlationID is maintained inside the payload itself and you can use it to track. Also in cases where there are logic apps and azure functions in the mix, I generally push the logging events from Logic Apps to the application insights

Comment: @MandarDharmadhikari , Thanks for the input. Do you use Application Insights or Log Analytics?

Comment: @MandarDharmadhikari I also think that this is the only solution. Why don't you post it as an answer?